# Can you precompile Julia scripts in Python's julia module and call them without Main.eval(*)?

Tags: python, julia, pycall

I'm trying to call Julia scripts with Python to get some better speeds on functions I need to call a huge number of times (for some Monte Carlo type analyses). I've sucessfully installed and run Julia scripts in python via:

```
from julia import Main as JuliaMain  # julia().<something> --> is deprecated, use Main instead
# julia.install()  # use when running for the first time
script_julia = JuliaMain.include('juliascript.jl')
```

in addition to ensuring that PyCall is configured correctly in the Julia runtime.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but with my current understanding, this will *compile* any functions inside `juliascript.jl` in the sense that Julia will figure out what the return type is and go through whatever motions it does when you call and/or define a function for the first time.

Consider that the defined function in `juliascript.jl` is something like:

```
function f(x,y)
    z = x + y
    return z
end
```

If I call this function with `x = JuliaMain.eval("f(1, 3)")`, will the speed of this function reflect a Julia function called more than once, or is it effectively being "recompiled" each time?
Furthermore, how can I call these defined functions without having to convert my request to a string to do so? I know [from the docs](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) that you can set and get variables directly, but this seems quite clumsy, and I was hoping there was a more elegant way, such as something in the format of `JuliaMain.f(x, y)` or `JuliaMain.runfunction.f(x, y)`, etc.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/64241265#64241265   however I might be biased here. If it is missing some information that you need please let me know

Comment: Good reference! I didn't see this. Is moving it into a package a strict requirement, or is there a way to go from where I am currently at (using .include from a script within the same folder) to running the function from something like `myjuliascript.f([1,2],5)`?

Comment: Packages get precompiled (so they are faster in subsequent runs) and can be loaded as a package in Python. Moreover they come with their own virtual environment via `Project.toml`. Why it is not a strict requirement you would need a very good reason no to do so and generally not using a package would make your life (including production deployments) much more painful. Last but not least a Julia package can be statically compiled into Julia's system image.

Comment: Perfect, this answers both questions, actually, as I was about to ask if the method I was using was precompiling the function, but it appears that it is not. If you put this into a response, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: since many people rely on this knowledge I rather closed this question and edited my previous post with comments to your answer. I prefer to keep all details in one place so people can easier find all info they need :-)