# No module named Julia

Tags: python-3.x, julia, pycall

I'm a new beginner with python und have recently installed Julia. And as I wrote "from julia import Main" in Jupyter note through Anaconda, an error would occur which is "no module named 'julia'". I don't know which part is wrong or is this about the path of the installation of Julia? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1ANG.png)

I would appreciate it so much if you could help me.

Comment: You normally program Julia in a Jupyter notebook with a Julia kernel. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps you want to call Julia from Python? If this is true please have a look at my tutorial here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/64241265#64241265

Comment: Everything works until the fourth setp, as I worte “from julia import Main” another error occured said that "ERROR: zsh: segmentation fault  python3"

Comment: Please provide a detailed description what steps are you taking starting from the command line along with all commands and errors.  `segmentation fault python3` could be a possible mismatch of versions (running 32-bit Python with 64-bit Julia) or maybe just a Pkg.build("PyCall") could be enough. Hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Thank you. @PrzemyslawSzufel, I just made it. The problem is that I have to set up the path right first and then Pkg.build("PyCall") as you said

Answer (score 4):

"from x import y" is the syntax for importing Python packages in a Python script or notebook, but as you probably know, Julia is a separate language of its own, not a Python package.

If you want to use Julia in a Jupyter notebook, you will instead generally want to change the whole Jupyter *kernel* to Julia from Python, rather than just adding a package (though see comment from Przemyslaw above if you want to call Julia *from* Python for any reason).

The easiest way to install a Julia kernel for Jupyter and start a notebook using that kernel is to just start the Jupyter notebook *from* Julia. In other words, first start Julia, so that you have a Julia REPL that looks something like the image below, and then type

```
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia") # If IJulia is not already installed
julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook()
```

[image: Starting a Jupyter instance from Julia]

which will open up a Jupyter instance with a Julia kernel installed, from which you can open a new notebook using that Julia kernel

[image: Starting a new Julia notebook]

which should look like the following (note the Julia symbol in the upper right corner)

[image: Julia running in Jupyter notebook]

Note that at no point in this process do you use Python or Anaconda for anything, and note also that in Julia there is no `from` keyword and also generally no such thing as `Main`

Comment: I did as you said, but the same error still occurs "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'julia'"

Comment: Perhaps I did not make my point sufficiently clear: there is no scenario in which you should _ever_ type `from julia import Main`. That is a python-specific syntax and has no meaning in Julia.

Comment: I have elaborated a bit more above

Comment: maybe my description is kinda of chaos, but I have solved the problem yesterday, the whole problem is that the "PATH" was not settled to the enviroment, and after that I can do everything as usual. Thank you anyway :)