# Is it possible to write julia code in python and run it?

Tags: python, julia

I want to write the julia code in the .py file, and when running the py file, the julia code can also pass normally, is this possible?
I am using text editor VScode, python3.10 and julia1.7.2.

Actually, I know it's a bit whimsical, but today I saw python code running successfully in julia. So I wonder if it can be reversed.

```
module MyModule
using PyCall
function __init__()
    py"""
    import numpy as np
    def one(x):
        return np.sin(x) ** 2 + np.cos(x) ** 2
    """
end
two(x) = py"one"(x) + py"one"(x)
end
MyModule.two(2)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're really trying to do, or why. Please explain in more detail. Obviously the Python interpreter won't understand Julia as they're different languages. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/ . Which mentions in the first paragraph: "the Julia C API can also be used to build further language bridges (e.g. calling Julia from Python or C#)."

Comment: So the answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: "I am using text editor VScode": that is of absolutely no importance. Your OS might be more important (but unlikely).

Comment: I think this could be considered a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/64241265

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [PyJulia](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

```py
from julia import Main
Main.eval("sin.(xs)")
```

Comment: As an addition this is a nice post about it https://blog.esciencecenter.nl/how-to-call-julia-code-from-python-8589a56a98f2

Comment: Also, all details you will need in the section [Using Julia in Python](https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/stable/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0106_-_Further_topics.html#Using-Julia-in-Python) of this course.

Answer (score 2):

[JuliaCall](https://cjdoris.github.io/PythonCall.jl/dev/juliacall/) is another possible solution.

```py
from juliacall import Main as jl
jl.println("Hello from Julia!")
```