# julia.install() fails on python import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, julia

I am trying to run a Julia script from python. I have Julia 1.6.4 installed (also tried 1.7.3) and installed `pip install julia` from Pycharm's terminal in the virtual environment. When importing julia and then running `julia.install()` I get the following error message:

I use Pycharm with a virtual environment with Python 3.9.7 for my project. However, I have also tried different python versions in different virtual environments or by using the base python installed. All give the same error.

Also, ~/.julia/packages/PyCall/*/deps/build.log does not exist for me.

````
[ Info: Trying to import PyCall...
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 12, in <module>
    GenericAlias = type(list[int])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<user>\PycharmProjects\<project>\venv\lib\site-packages\julia\tools.py", line 118, in install
    raise PyCallInstallError("Installing", output)
julia.tools.PyCallInstallError: Installing PyCall failed.
** Important information from Julia may be printed before Python's Traceback **
Some useful information may also be stored in the build log file
`~/.julia/packages/PyCall/*/deps/build.log`.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Julia needs to have PyCall installed
2. PyCall in Julia needs to be configured to use the same Python that you are using to call Julia from

For more information see this post:
[I have a high-performant function written in Julia, how can I use it from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/64241265#64241265)

Comment: I had already tried the procedure explained in the post you shared, however I kept running into the same problem. You were right that PyCall in Julia was not configured to the same Python as I use to call Julia. 
The problem was that I also had python installed via the Windows Store which Julia automatically chose as PYTHONHOME. Removing that python and reinstalling Julia afterwards solved it.