Unable to resolve an error while loading a Python-Julia package
I am trying to install a package named 'quanestimation', written in Python and Julia, which I will use to perform numerical calculations for my research. I followed the installation instructions provided on the package website. This package requires several open-source packages in Python (version 3.10) and Julia (version 1.10).
However, when I load the package with
from quanestimation import *

on my Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:
----- Download Julia -----
downloading Julia release for 1.10.0-mac-x86_64
downloading from https://julialang- 
s3.julialang.org/bin/mac/x64/1.10/julia-1.10.0-mac64.dmg
100% [..................................................] 
145732619 / 145732619
finished downloading julia-1.10.0-mac64.dmg
----- Install Julia -----
remove previous Julia installation: /Applications/Julia-1.10.app
install Julia to /Applications/Julia-1.10.app
add /Users/jayanth_jayakumar/.local/bin to PATH
~/.bashrc will be modified
if you're not using BASH, then you'll need manually add 
/Users/jayanth_jayakumar/.local/bin to your PATH
you need to restart your current shell to update PATH
ERROR:julia_project:No julia executable found or installed.
----- Post Installation -----
remove downloaded files...
remove /Users/jayanth_jayakumar/julia-1.10.0-mac64.dmg
Done!
Install from jill returned 'None'.
Initialization failed. You may try running again

I have already installed Julia 1.10 on my macOS system and also added the directory /Users/jayanth_jayakumar/.local/bin to my PATH. However, I'm still encountering the same error stating that 'No julia executable found or installed'.
I would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions that will help me to resolve this error and successfully load the package.
Thanks.

There are two libraries involved. PythonCall in Julia and juliacall in Python. The reason your code does not work is that the installation needs to be symmetric. PythonCall needs to be Pkg.build("PythonCall") with ENV["PYTHON"] pointing to the same Python that juliacall is installed and juliacall needs to point to the same Julia. You could perhaps try to start with v.tralala's explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/75483586#75483586
